# Specific language Properties files not loaded according to the language selection using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

My plan is to develop a web application with different language support. Checked the spring internalization concepts and did an application like that. But here the problem is application loading the language properties file which was specified as a defaultLocale. Verified the other StackOverflow questions and other links as well, but not the success.

spring-hibernate.xml file snap-shot  is,

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<bean       
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource
">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>classpath:global</value>
                <!-- <value>classpath:global_en</value>  -->
                <value>classpath:db-fields</value>
                <value>classpath:package</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="language" />
</bean>

<bean  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMap
ping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
       <list>
        <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
       </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Jsp file is,

```
<style type="text/css">
select#languagedropdown {
margin: 0px 0px 0px 550px;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
text-indent: 1px;
text-overflow: '';
height:25px;
font-weight:bold;
}
</style>

<select id="languagedropdown"
                name="dropdown" onchange="window.location.href=this.value;">
    <option value="">&nbsp;---Language---&nbsp;</option>
    <option value="?language=en">English</option>
    <option value="?language=fa">&#1601;&#1575;&#1585;&#1587;&#1740;
        / &#1601;&#1575;&#1585;&#1587;&#1740;</option>
    <option value="?language=fr">Fran&ccedil;ais</option>
    <option value="?language=de">Deutsche</option>
    <option value="?language=ar">&#1593;&#1585;&#1576;&#1609;</option>
</select>
```

Please help me guys in soving this, tried the following,
http://javainsimpleway.com/714/
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-internationalization-i18n-localization-tutorial-example/
http://www.journaldev.com/2610/spring-mvc-internationalization-i18n-and-localization-l10n-example
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Comment: Remove the `ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping` definition and use `mvc:interceptors` to register your interceptors.

Comment: @M.Deinum, thanks for the reply, tried it but still facing the issue.